# What are these sea behemoths in One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

The crew escapes from these behemoths shortly before arriving on the island chain with Bellamy.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are shadows, not monsters. These are explained by the fact that Sky Island is so high up in the air, the distance that the shadow is travelling is very far, making shadows cast very large.

Here you can see the same effect where Luffy's shadow is seen:

[image: Picture from anime: Luffy's giant shadow]

Answer (score 0):

skypien giants i thing almost the same as the  oes from the florian tryangle the spear and there is no way a shadow in the sea and  the shadow above is in the air these were throwing spears unless the things at the florian triangles were shadows.but they still may be shadows who knows they had wings.